# Java Play! 2.0 for eclipse

Tags: java, windows, playframework

I have problems to create a eclipse project with eclipsify in Play!.

I've downloaded Play! from http://www.playframework.org/

I extracted it and opend my cmd (I am using windows btw)

I changed my directory to

```
cd C:\Users\kanta\Downloads\play-2.0.2\play-2.0.2
```

Then i created a new applciation with:

- `play new myApp`
- `myApp`

But now I am stuck, I don't know how to use `eclipsify`

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/IDE
I don't know where I can find eclipsify.

I've tried this:

```
play eclipsify myApp
```

and

```
play myApp eclipsify
```

This resulted in "This is not a Play application".

**..::ANSWER::..**

For me it worked like this:

PATH

c:\windows\system32\;c:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin\;c:\play

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following steps

1. `play new myapp`
2. `cd myapp`
3. `play`
4. `eclipsify`

To clarify what is going on here

1 - creates a new play application,

2 - changes into the myapp directory

3 - starts the play SBT console, where you can execute the range of play commands

4 - runs the eclipsify command

Comment: Hm this doesn't work either. The folder myapp only contains: app,conf,public,project,.gitignore,README. http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/PlayConsole  Maybe the 2.0.2 is buggy I'll try another version

Comment: i am using a release candidate, but performed these exact steps and it worked fine...make sure Play is on your PATH

Comment: Yeah I think i didn't really understand how to add the PATH. http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/Installing

They say I should update the PATH in the environment variables. I don't even know what this means.

Comment: Okay I know how to add the path. But what is the correct path ?
In the windows environment variables -> name = play , value = C:\play-2.0.3-RC2  But it doesn't work. I guess i took the wrong path?

Comment: Modify the PATH variable. Add the path to the play.bat script at the end of the current PATH variable.

Comment: I still can't figure it out , sry i feel a little bit stupid. :(  Could you post what you have changed?

Comment: i am running on a Mac, so not quite the same. For windows, you have to change the System PATH variable. lots of posts online, but here is an example - http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/NhYCh.jpg  Sorry for the german windows, but this should be correct, right? Still doesn't work. Well I think I should post this question in a different forum.

Comment: no...PATH should have c:\play\ appended to the end of the variable, and it should be a directory, not a specific file. PATH should be something like `c:\windows\system32\;c:\windows\System32\Wbem;c\;\play\`